# Set the value of an input field with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, automation

For that, I need to collect data from a table generated by a web page. But when I insert the values ​​with Javascript, a problem occurs. In the entry of type date, when inserting a value like "

```
document.querySelector().value = '2023-02-06'
```

" does not work, because when clicking on another element of the screen, the value of the entry of type date returns to the value standard.

When inserting the value with .value, it changes the value in the form, but in the HTML it remains the same.

```
document.querySelector("#root > div.pushable.sidebar-content > div.ui.vertical.ui.overlay.left.visible.sidebar.menu > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(8) > input[type=date]").value = '2023-02-06';
'2023-02-06'
```

```
<input type="date" max="2023-02-07" value="2023-02-07">
```

Comment: the page I want to change the date with JavaScript is this: 
https://tempo.inmet.gov.br/TabelaEstacoes/A001

Comment: *... but in the HTML it remains the same* — if you're looking at "view source", that won't ever change. That shows you what the page looked like when received from the server. If you use your browser debugger, you will see the value change.

Comment: Also I *strongly* suggest you get away from very very specific, structurally rigid selector strings. That practice will make your life very difficult over time as your application evolves. (*edit* to be fair I didn't notice the "web-scraping" tag)

Comment: Got it but even when I click to generate the table the debugger value changes to default for some reason

Comment: Maybe the page is being reloaded. You can see whether that's happening via the Network developer tab.